# Adding a keyboard layout in the Guest session is not permanent

Tags: keyboard-layout, guest-session

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric. I have the default/administrator user but I also allow Guest sessions in my netbook. I have 2 keyboard layouts setup for my main user: English and Greek.

The problem is that whenever a Guest logs in, there is only one keyboard layout installed: the English one. Is there a way to add the Greek keyboard layout for Guest users and make this change permanent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 11.10 netbook edition?

Comment: I guess it's not netbook edition anymore. I edited on the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried System->Preferences->Keyboard->Layouts->Apply System-Wide?

Comment: I saw this in an answer to a similar question but can't find this option at all. In the "System Settings" there is a "Keyboard Layout" option but there is no "Apply System-Wide" option.